# Unlocked iPhone replacement

Tags: iphone, unlock

If an iPhone is locked, then unlocked and then replaced for a refurbished one in an Apple Store, **will the new one remain unlocked?**

Comment: Yes of course. And Apple does not issue refurbished devices. They only provide new replacements.

Comment: @cksum I was told by an Apple Store that replacements are, in fact, refurbished devices. I was actually talking about a situation where initially the iPhone was locked, then it was unlocked and then replaced.

Comment: You should edit your answer as that is not clear. And in that case, no, you won't receive an unlocked device from Apple. Also, Apple does not issue refurbished devices. They have made it quite clear in the past that the devices in the black boxes are new and not returbs.

Comment: @cksum Could you provide any kind of source where Apple *makes quite clear* that those are not refurbished? As Tokiema states, I was told, in an Apple Store, too, that the replacements where, indeed, refurbished. Even more, one of the latest devices I got replaced had a little *flaw* in the border.

Comment: @cksum Apple's [Express Replacement Service In-Warranty Terms and Conditions](http://images.apple.com/legal/sales-support/terms/docs/iphone_ars_emea_uk.pdf) states that they will mail or deliver to your designated location a **new or refurbished replacement iPhone**.

Comment: Yep, you're right. They are providing refurbs now.

Answer (score 1):

Locking has to do with the device itself, not your SIM card or cellular account. So you would need to have the new device unlocked as well. Assuming, though, that you qualified to have the initial device unlocked (per whatever terms and conditions your carrier specifies), you would presumably be able to have the new one unlocked without any problem.